# How to change the screen size on Android Telnet Client device

Tags: android, client, telnet

We have installed the GSW ConnectBot ([Android Telnet Client](https://www.georgiasoftworks.com/connectbot-client-android)) on our warehouse scanners (We use [Janam's XT](https://www.janam.com/products/xt-series) devices).

Our truck mount tablets are much larger than the ones that we carry on our belts, and the ones we use in the office are a 3rd size.

How do I configure and change the screen size for each device? I want to be able to specify the number of rows and columns visible based on the specific tablet size.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

The application programming can be modified to detect the screen size and adjust the output to accommodate it. Often this is the hard way.

For the Android Telnet Client mentioned you can configure the screen size on the client residing on the device, there is a simple menu to accomplish it, HOWEVER you also need to change it on the server, typically using the "mode con" command on a Windows Server. This sets the number of rows and columns. I am not sure the analogous command on a Linux Server. Basically this sets the screen on the client device and what the server presents to the same size.

This can also be done programmatically on the server (at least a Windows Server), when the telnet connection is made, a program is launched that can run the "mode con" command. There are many more details, but I think this points you in the correct direction.

I hope this helps
Socrates